# Playing vocals on instrument

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music, vocal-cords

I’m not advanced sooo just wanted to ask- i found a music sheets with vocal and accompaniment. As no one will sing for me i need accompaniment. Is it possible to merge it? I play on piano, so I can do vocals with one hand what with another?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you are asking. Yes, you can play the melody and accompany yourself. "...so I can do vocals with one hand what with another?" Are you asking about what you should do with the hand that is not playing the melody?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do this, and I realize that this is a pretty difficult situation to be in, especially if you're not familiar with this sort of thing.

One solution is to sing while playing the accompaniment. I'm not sure if you've already ruled this out, though.

If the accompaniment is simple enough, you can find the main chords of the song, play them in the left hand, and pick out the melody with the right.

Another solution is to find a different arrangement. Depending on the popularity of the song you want to play, there could be a ton of arrangements out there. If you search "[song name] piano sheet," you might get some results. I also recommend the website https://musescore.org/en - search the song name in the search bar.

Yet another solution may be to record yourself playing the accompaniment and sing along with that, or find a pre-recorded accompaniment and sing with that. However, that would require you singing instead of playing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way the sheet music is written. Often when there are three lines, top sung, other two r.h. and l.h. piano, the r.h. part doesn't necessarily feature the melody line. After all it is the accompaniment. In this case you'll have to play r.h. and add the melody line somehow. Sometimes you'll be lucky and the melody is actually written as the series of top notes in r.h. along with partial chords.

Keep the l.h. as is for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

The piano part for a pop song often includes the vocal melody in the RH.  Generally this is not musically good - the accompaniment should support and complement the vocal but not just double it - but in your case it may be useful!  Play the printed piano part.  Is everything happening?